# receiving data after curl_easy_perform

Tags: c++, c, linux, libcurl

I have the following question: how can i write data returning with http-response in `char *` buffer? I've found several approaches:

1. use `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` or `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`. but `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` requires file pointer (`FILE *`). use of `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` with callback function seems to me as quirk...
2. use `curl_easy_send` and `curl_easy_recv`. but in this case i'll need to write all `POST` headers with hands...

Is there some other, more elegant approach? e.g. pass `char *` buffer pointer into some function to get http response in.

Answer (score 2):

Actually CURLOPT_WRITEDATA and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION can be used with any pointer type.  As long as your function is compatible with that pointer type.

For example:

```
    ...
    client_t *client;
    CURL *conn;
    ...
    curl_easy_setopt(conn, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, read_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(conn, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, client);
    ...

static size_t read_data(void *ptr,
                        size_t size,
                        size_t nmemb,
                        client_t *client)
{
     memcpy(client->data, ptr, size * nmemb);
     return size * nmemb;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, that's how it's supposed to be done. Oh, and don't forget that ptr might only be a chunk of  the whole response, depending on what options you've set with curl_easy_setopt.

Comment: It seems somewhat silly that curl doesn't provide a "how much data did you put in the buffer I gave you" call.