# void* to FILE*... is that possible?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm a complete newbie to all this stuff, and I'm developing a plugin. I need to upload a file using libcurl. The problem is that that file is not on the disk, pointer on it's content is passed to my plugin. So my question is that to upload a file I need FILE* var, but I'm having void*. What should I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could always write the data to a temporary file and then send that.

Comment: If all you have is a `void*` you can do *absolutely nothing* unless you know what type of data it points to so you can cast it. So, what is that pointer supposed to be?

Comment: @Jon: that's not true... he has a pointer to some unknown binary blob and its size (I suppose), you don't need anything more to upload this data/write it to file/in general store it somewhere.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: If the pointer points to a binary blob then it's actually an `unsigned char*`, which is what I meant.

Comment: yes! I have a size of content of a file. Temporary file is possible of cause... But I'm sure there's better solution

Comment: @Jon: if it's a binary blob its content is unknown, so no type actually makes sense. `unsigned char *` in these cases is just a convention (often used because with it pointer arithmetic allow you to move easily with byte offsets).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: In any case: my point is that you are *assuming* it's a binary blob. While that is probably true, it may also be some kind of opaque handle that we don't know about. It's the OP's job to provide this information.

Comment: @Jon: I agree on your point, although my assumption comes from the fact that he says "pointer on it's content is passed to my plugin".

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539137/receiving-data-after-curl-easy-perform/4543395#4543395

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform an upload using a read callback instead of providing a `FILE *`, as specified in [this example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html). In the callback then you can copy into the given buffer the data to upload.

Comment: I saw this example, there added `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);` does that mean that the file is really needed?

Comment: No, that is just an arbitrary parameter that will be provided as the first parameter to your read_callback function. You should probably use a pointer to some `struct` containing your `void *` and the size of the content.

Comment: Maybe you know why `error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'FILE*` is thrown by line  `size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);` in that example?

Comment: Because it's in C (where implicit cast to `void *` to any type of pointer is allowed), while you are compiling it in C++ (where a cast is needed); add the cast and it will work.