# C function conversion to c++

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I am experiencing a problem with C language while I am trying to adapt a callback written in C to C++. Compiler shows the following error:

```
error C2664: 'fread' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'void *' to 'FILE*'
1>Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
```

I found that this`size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream)`
needs a [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475624/conversion-from-void-to-pointer-to-non-void-requires-an-explicit-cast-line). I've tried, but nothing works. Here is the code:

```
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    curl_off_t nread;
    size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;
    fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
            " bytes from file\n", nread);
    return retcode;
}
```

Comment: While you could cast it, wouldn't it be easier to just change the parameter type to FILE *?  Would depend on the structure of the remainder that you haven't supplied.

Comment: __Please read the error message carefully__, it tells you what you can do to fix this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523318/void-to-file-is-that-possible

Comment: Use `static_cast<FILE*>(stream)` or `(FILE*)stream` to do this "Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void'..."

Comment: Turns out C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: Remarkable: the question never mentions **what the expected type is**. RTFM!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fread(ptr, size, nmemb, static_cast<FILE*>(stream))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of perfectly valid C code, that is not valid C++. Implicit type conversion of `void*` to any pointer type (and back) is explicitly allowed by the C standard.

[**§6.3.2.3 ¶ 2**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1):

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

But C++ only allows it in the direction of `void*`:

[**§4.11 ¶ 2**](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#2):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T”, where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The pointer value ([basic.compound]) is unchanged by this conversion.

The other direction is possible only with a cast.