# How to use libcurl in c++ to send POST to elasticsearch

Tags: c++, elasticsearch, libcurl

does anyone knows the exact syntax for using elasticsearch with libcurl?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
   CURL *curl;
   CURLcode res;

   curl = curl_easy_init();

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9200/bro-201409170900/http/ZinAvJ-ETT-mycy2jyRkdg/_update -d");
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"script\" : \"ctx._source.longitude += 3\"}");
   curl_easy_perform(curl);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

   return 1;
}
```

This code does ont update the longitude parameter and I don't know why.

Comment: have you checked that you got `CURLE_OK` as a results from `curl_easy_perform`. Check this: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html. Also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203436/c-api-for-elastic-search mention a C++ api for elasticsearch: https://github.com/QHedgeTech/cpp-elasticsearch

Comment: I bet the "-d" in the end of the URL shouldn't be there...

Comment: hey Daniel, This is the syntax for command line:                                                             curl http://localhost:9200/bro-201409170900/http/ZinAvJ-ETT-mycy2jyRkdg/_update -d '{ "script" : "ctx._source.longitude += 2"}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should not specify the "-d' in the url. The command line tool is just build on top of libcurl.
If you want to see what the c code for the post request would look like you  could use the [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) option with command line .

example :

```
curl localhost:9200/bro-201409170900/http/ZinAvJ-ETT-mycy2jyRkdg/… -d '{ "script" : "ctx._source.longitude += 2"}' --libcurl  output.c
```

A simple "C" implementation  would look something on these lines

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
   CURL *curl;
   CURLcode res;
   char *postFields = "{\"script\" : \"ctx._source.longitude += 3\"}";

   curl = curl_easy_init();
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:9200/bro-201409170900/http/ZinAvJ-ETT-mycy2jyRkdg/_update");
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,postFields);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,strlen(postFields));
   res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

   return res;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, by the way do you have any idea how to stop the printing which cause by the 'curl_easy_perform' and send it to c string instead : {"_index":"bro-201409170900","_type":"http","_id":"ZinAvJ-ETT-mycy2jyRkdg","_version":31}

Comment: remove the Verobse setting i.e. "curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1)" to prevent it show up on the console. If you want the response string from POST request you need to use the WRITEDATA ,WRITEFUNCTION from libcurl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539137/receiving-data-after-curl-easy-perform/4543395#4543395